# Can a single object have multiple references?

Tags: android, object

I just have a little silly doubt,

In this code:

```
 ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_TITLE, book.getTitle()); // get title 
        values.put(KEY_AUTHOR, book.getAuthor()); // get author
db.insert(TABLE_BOOKS, // table
                null, //nullColumnHack
                values);
```

The `values` hold both the `KEY_TITLE` and `KEY_AUTHOR` So my question is, can a single object `values` hold multiple references ?

```
values.put(KEY_TITLE, book.getTitle()); // get title 
values.put(KEY_AUTHOR, book.getAuthor()); // get author
```

Comment: I dont get the question here?both the keys are different.Its as good as ,the ContentValues is as good as a map.I do not see anything wrong with you're code.

Comment: @Droidekas Please read my question again. Of course there is nothing wrong. i jut wanted to know how ??

Comment: @Droidekas Please see the answer MD Malik and Mr 32 this is what I was expecting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes a single object can hold multiple reference, making sure that declaration of `KEY_TITLE` and `KEY_AUTHOR` are different.

If they are the same then you will be left with only one value. That of which will be the last one.

You can understand it better from this [link](http://binarynerd.com/java-tutorials/advanced-java/using-java-hashmaps.html)

Comment: Ah ! 1. So you mean `ContentValues` is collections ?
        2. So `values` store all the combinations and if any values has to be retrieved then it has to be retrieved by a key ?

Comment: @CheckBox 1) yes 2) yes

Answer (score 1):

Yes

As defination says

> This class is used to store a set of values that the ContentResolver
>   can process.

Using different `Key` name you can store multiple values in single object of this class.